# Real numbers as a vector space with non-standard multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{k}=\mathbb{R}$. Let's define operation $\odot:\mathbb{k}\times X\to X$ by $\lambda \odot u=\lambda^2\cdot u$, where $\cdot$ is the regular multiplication. Is it possible to make $X$ vector space over $\mathbb{k}$?

**My approach:** Suppose $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{k}$ with operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$. Then all axioms of vector space should be true and in particular $$(\alpha+\beta)\odot x=\alpha \odot x\oplus\beta\odot x.$$

Then LHS is $(\alpha+\beta)^2x=\alpha^2x+2\alpha\beta x+\beta^2x$ and RHS is $\alpha^2 x\oplus \beta^2x$. So $$\alpha^2 x\oplus \beta^2x=\alpha^2x+2\alpha\beta x+\beta^2x$$
taking $\alpha=\beta=1$ we will get that $x\oplus x=4x$. I was trying to use it t express $x\oplus y$ but failed.

Would be thankful for any ideas how to continue my approach?

Comment: You have taken $\alpha=1,\beta=1$, now also try $\alpha=1,\beta=-1$.

Comment: @Rahul Why not an official answer?

Comment: @Rahul, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(-1)\odot x=(1)\odot x=x$, so

$$(-1+1)\odot x=0\odot x=0=x\oplus x=2\odot x$$

which gives $x=0$ for all vectors $x$, a contradiction.